# All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification. Found versions 18.3.0, 17.1.1, 17.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, admob

I am trying to add google admob to my app. however I used previous answers in others topics. it does not worked. 
here is my gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
}
```

the error is: All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification. Found versions 18.3.0, 17.1.1, 17.0.1.

Comment: full details of Project **bulid.gradle**

Comment: have you using **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'**